# Device reliability by components failure probability

Tags: probability

A device is assembled using three type of components: A, B and C. Device reliability is dependant of components failure probability. Any of component failure is a single cause to device failure.

Device is assembled from:
A)  20 components of A type where each component probability of failure is 0.1
B)  2 components of B type where each component probability of failure is 0.7
C)  8 components of C type where each component probability of failure is 0.2

In the case when device fail, what is probability that it is caused by failure of A type, B type or C type component classification?

I tried to solve it by:
Component failure probability for the device: 
Type A: (20/30)*0.1*(2/30)*0.3*(8/30)*0.8=0.0002844,,

It doesn’t look right and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I used one calculation that looks right, but I am not sure:

Comment: Type A: 20*0.1*(0.9^19)*(0.3^2)*(0.8^8)=0.0040794

Comment: The device works $\color{grey}{\textrm{if and only if}}$ all $30(=20+2+8)$ components work, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is no paralelism in components assembly. Failure of single component, regardles of classification type will cause device failure.

Comment: I tried again and I think that I got right result. I need positive/negative confirmation:

Comment: Type A component failure: 20*0.1*(0.9^19)*(0.3^2)*(0,8^8)=0.00408. In same way I calculated the probability  for failures of components A and B types respectively: (B=0.00857, C=0.00367).